# OpenLayers 3 function resolution?

Tags: openlayers, resolution

I'd like to make visible my var text between two resolutions so to speak between 150 and 50 for instance.
but I didn't find how to do this yet.

```
var communes = new ol.layer.Vector({
        title:'communes',
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({     
            url: 'communes.geojson'}),
        style: function(feature, resolution) {
var text = resolution < 150 ? feature.get('nom_comm') : '';
if (!styleCache[text]) {
  styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    })
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
var text = resolution < 150 ? feature.get('nom_comm') : '';
```

with

```
var test = (resolution < 150 && resolution > 50 ) ? feature.get('nom_comm') : '';
```

Comment: thx. This seems to work even with only one &.

Comment: The single '&' is a Bitwise AND operator.  Although it happens to evaluate correctly here, you're best avoiding it, partly to make the code more coherent.